# Difference between processor , component and end point

Tags: apache-camel

I am studying Apache Camel.

Could some one please explain the difference between a processor, component and endpoint with regard to Apache Camel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All whom are new to Apache Camel I suggest to read this article which explains really well what Camel is, and has an example to go along.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/open-source-integration-apache

Another great piece is chatper 1 of the Camel in Action book, which can be freely downloaded from here: http://www.manning.com/ibsen/Camel_ch01_update.pdf

Disclaimer: I am co-author of that book.

And there is this old by good tutorial that still applies today: http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident.html

And you can find more tutorials / examples on the Camel website

- http://camel.apache.org/tutorials.html
- http://camel.apache.org/examples.html

And there is also some links to 3rd party blogs/articles/videos about Camel, where you can find some great information:

- http://camel.apache.org/articles.html

Comment: This is helpful, but I'd still hope for a brief explanation of processor/component/endpoint...

Answer (score 10):

A component allows you to talk with other systems. It allows you to send or receive messages and encapsulates the protocol to deal with another system. For e.g. jms-component allows to talk with JMS brokers.

An endpoint is nothing but the channel by which you send or receive a message through component e.g. "jms:queue:order" this defines a jms endpoint which is a queue from where your (jms) component will either consume or publish a message.

While a processor is piece of code which goes in between routes. There you write code to manipulate (transform/enrich/extract etc.) the message or have some integration logic.

For more details refer to camel's [documentation](http://camel.apache.org)

Comment: This answer mixes up some terminology. A Component is a factory for Endpoints. Parsing "jms:queue:order", Camel will use the "jms" scheme to lookup the JmsComponent in the Component registry, which will create a JMS queue Endpoint named "order". The Endpoint creates Producers and Consumers to handle the message. This is reflected in the Javadoc for [JmsComponent](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-jms/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/jms/JmsComponent.html): see that is has methods for creating JMS Endpoints.